# Tool to visualize YAML files and model classes

Tags: doctrine, symfony1, netbeans-6.9

I'm working with Symfony and Doctrine ORM, and I'm wondering if there's tool/plugin for Netbeans that will allow me to visualize my schema.yml and model classes, sort of along the lines of Visual Studio's entity framework.

Comment: A (deleted) answer gave [this resource](https://cedricpoon.github.io/reyaml-web/). It looks pretty good, so I am adding it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind it is not plug-in for Netbeans try [ORM Designer](http://www.orm-designer.com/).

It is a stand-alone application, but it has the functionality you need. With it you can import and visualize your Yaml schema and you can even edit it the same way as in Visual Studio.

Comment: I just want to notice that we renamed ORM Designer3 to Skipper and now application is available on [www.skipper18.com](http://www.skipper18.com)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why does netbeans not let you see the schema.yml file, but you can open it with many regular applications like notepad or gedit if you want.